# How does one derive quantum gates from a custom gate systematically?

Tags: circuit-construction, matrix-representation

I have been trying to solve a puzzle (not homework) in which I need to derive a quantum circuit from given a superposition, $|\psi\rangle$, where

$$
|00\rangle: 20\%\\
|10\rangle: 40\%\\
|11\rangle: 40\%\\
$$

and I must generate an output of

$$
|00\rangle: 20\%\\
|11\rangle: 80\%\\
$$

I started by writing $|\psi\rangle$ out as a ratios of the input probabilities wich somehow has to get to  the output via a transformation C
$$
{\Huge C}\begin{bmatrix}1 \\\ 0 \\\ 2\\\ 2 \end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}1 \\\ 0 \\\ 0\\\ 4 \end{bmatrix}
$$

It was then simple enough to determine that what was actually happening was
$${\Huge C}=\begin{bmatrix}1 & 0 & 0 & 0\\\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\\ 0 & 0 & 1 & 1\end{bmatrix}$$

My question is then, how can I derive which primitive quantum logic gates should be used to compose this operation, C? Even if it is intuitive to some people, I cannot recognise it and would appreciate a step-by-step way to break it down into regular gates. Ideally the solution would be able to generalise for other situations  where I need to derive what logic gates are used to produce certain results.

If there is a problem with the formulation of the question or terminology used, feel free to suggest an edit. I am quite new to this.

### Edit 1

Thanks for the comments. I have been working through the terminology in what you all have said and I can provide some amended information (though I can't personally see how it has a bearing on the solution).

The puzzle actually has a way of getting the amplitudes, yet none of them have a complex component. So if I got his right, the input state vector looks like this:

$$
\begin{bmatrix}\sqrt{0.2} + 0i \\\ 0 \\\ \sqrt{0.4} + 0i\\\ \sqrt{0.4} + 0i \end{bmatrix}
$$

I also have no idea how to represent the "desired" vector. I do now understand why whatever C is needs to be unitary, but I don't know how to get a C at all now.

Comment: C isn't unitary so it's not a quantum operation.

Comment: State vector should be amplitudes, not probabilities, no? And these may be complex-valued.

Comment: Your general approach of inverting $C$ is not bad but your matrix $C$ is not reversible/unitary.   See [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unitary_matrix).  Also your wavefunction $|\psi\rangle$ is composed of probabilities, but it needs to be amplitudes/roots of probabilities.

Comment: controlled-Hadamard controlled off the first qubit targeting the second qubit. $$\left(\begin{array}{cccc} 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1/\sqrt{2} & 1/\sqrt{2} \\ 0 & 0 & 1/\sqrt{2} & -1/\sqrt{2} \end{array}\right)$$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A quantum system is not specified by probabilities, but probability amplitudes. I'm going to assume that what you want to do is the conversion
$$
\frac{1}{\sqrt{5}}\left(\begin{array}{c} 1 \\ 0 \\ \sqrt{2} \\ \sqrt{2} \end{array}\right)\rightarrow\frac{1}{\sqrt{5}}\left(\begin{array}{c} 1 \\ 0 \\ 0  \\2 \end{array}\right)
$$
The way that I look at this, it says that the amplitudes on the states where the first qubit is in $|0\rangle$ just stay the same. I only have to change things if the first qubit is in the $|1\rangle$ state. Hence, we're looking for a unitary controlled-$U$ where
$$
U\frac{1}{\sqrt{5}}\left(\begin{array}{c}
\sqrt{2} \\ \sqrt{2}
\end{array}\right)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{5}}\left(\begin{array}{c}
0 \\ 2
\end{array}\right),
$$
subject to the constraint that $U$ is unitary, meaning $UU^\dagger=I$ and $U^\dagger U=I$. You can construct such a matrix very easily. In particular, multiply both sides of the previous equation by $U^\dagger$. We have
$$
U^\dagger\left(\begin{array}{c} 0 \\ 1 \end{array}\right)=U^\dagger U\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\left(\begin{array}{c} 1 \\ 1 \end{array}\right)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\left(\begin{array}{c} 1 \\ 1 \end{array}\right).
$$
Now, let's temporarily write out
$$
U^\dagger=\left(\begin{array}{cc} a & b \\ c & d \end{array}\right).
$$
Hence,
$$
U^\dagger\left(\begin{array}{c} 0 \\ 1 \end{array}\right)=\left(\begin{array}{c} c \\ d \end{array}\right).
$$
Thus, we can easily identify the elements $c$ and $d$ as both being $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$. We have identified the second column of $U^\dagger$.

So, if we can identify the first column, i.e. the values
$$
U^\dagger\left(\begin{array}{c} 1 \\ 0 \end{array}\right),
$$
we're done. Note, however, that
$$
\left(U^\dagger\left(\begin{array}{c} 0 \\ 1 \end{array}\right)\right)^\dagger U^\dagger\left(\begin{array}{c} 1 \\ 0 \end{array}\right)=\left(\begin{array}{cc} 1 & 0 \end{array}\right)UU^\dagger\left(\begin{array}{c} 1 \\ 0 \end{array}\right)=\left(\begin{array}{cc} 1 & 0 \end{array}\right)\left(\begin{array}{c} 1 \\ 0 \end{array}\right)=0
$$
but it is also
$$
=\left(\begin{array}{cc} a^\star & b^\star \end{array}\right)\left(\begin{array}{c} c \\ d \end{array}\right)=a^\star c+b^\star d.
$$
Said another way, the first column must be orthogonal in order to give unitarity. Also, each column must have length 1. There's some freedom in the choice - we can have any $a=e^{i\phi}$ with $b=-e^{i\phi}$, but a natural one would be $\phi=0$, thus giving
$$
U^\dagger=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\left(\begin{array}{cc} 1 & 1 \\ -1 & 1 \end{array}\right)=\sqrt{Y}
$$
and hence
$$
U=\sqrt{Y}^\dagger.
$$
Thus, the overall operation you're looking for is controlled-$\sqrt{Y}^\dagger$, which is written as
$$
\left(\begin{array}{cccc}
1 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} & -\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \\
0 & 0 & \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} & \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}
\end{array}\right)
$$

This can subsequently be decomposed into more elementary gates if necessary, but since you don't specify what you consider to be your building blocks, I can't be more specific.

Comment: I've been trying to understand your third and fourth paragraph. Would you be willing to tease out the reasoning/terminology a bit? I understand what those things mean on their own but I don't think I'm making the right connections.

Comment: You mean the bit that goes from the action of $U$ on one particular vector to producing the matrix form of $U$?

Comment: Yes. Particularly where you introduce U dagger. Like, for instance, you say "that's the second column of U dagger". I'm not sure which vector you mean (and I'm also assuming you mean a vector), because neither of the vectors are represented in U's matrix.